# JS doesn't find tags inside a custom tags in the HTML page

Tags: html, jquery, api, vps, custom-tags

I have a problem in my project.
In the "index.html" page there's a custom tag, and inside that there's a DIV that work as a button.
My project has a js file, and it's "script.js". This file has the code that listens when the DIV is clicked. I'm using the jquery library too.
The file "main.js" generates the custom tag.

index.html - CODE

```
<body>
   <custom></custom>
   <script content="text/html; src="//mymarialuisa.com/js/main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

What's inside custom tag ? - CODE

```
<div class='toggle_mic' id='switch'>
  <div class='toggle-text-off'>OFF</div>
  <div class='toggle-text-on'>ON</div>
</div>
```

script.js - CODE

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.toggle_mic').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("click");
 });
});
```

I developed all of these files normally, without the custom tag or loading the "main.js" file on a remote server, and everything worked right. Then, when I introduced the custom tag and I loaded the "main.js" file on a remote server, the DIV button stopped working.
The "script.js" file is correctly loaded; everything is correctly loaded, but when I click on the DIV (.toggle_mic) it doesn't work.

The browser console doesn't report me any errors!!!

Comment: You have two frameworks here. jquery and vue. You need to understand how they work. And perhaps choose one over the other. Ideally you should be setting your click behavior in vue, NOT jquery. The `document.ready` function will run when the original DOM is loaded, _before_ vue works it magic.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you **should** be [wiring up your click actions in vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html), not jquery.

Keep in mind that when `document.ready()` runs from `jquery`, vue may not have completed updating the DOM. If you insist on using jquery use jquery's [`on`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `click` to handle dynamically added objects.

If you have `custom` inside an identifiable use that as your parent container, otherwise use `body`, but you should avoid that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('body').on('click', '.toggle_mic', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   console.log("click");
 });
});
```